# php xpath crawler not retreiving the whole text within a tag

Tags: php, xpath

I tried to develop a crawler in php that keeps track on the best price of some products on a web shop comparison site. I am having a txt file with links which I crawl and I take from those links exactly the information I need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='crawlerStyle.css'>
</head>
<body>
<div class='div-table-row'>
<div class='div-table-col-title'><span class='span-title'>Name</span></div>
<div class='div-table-col-title'><span class='span-title'>Best Pricerunner price</span></div>
</div>
<?php 

$myfile = fopen("urls.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
if ($myfile) {
    while (($line = fgets($myfile)) !== false) {
        @follow_links($line);
    }
    fclose($myfile);
}

function getPRPrice($priceTag){
    return substr($priceTag, 2).",00 DKK";
}
function follow_links($line) {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($line));
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);    

    $name = $xpath->query( '////span[@class="fn" and @itemprop="name"]')->item(0);
    $price = $xpath->query( '//ul[@class="itemlist" and li[@class="shoppingcol" and p[@class="button" and a[@class="button-a google-analytic-retailer-data"]]]]/*/*/*/*/*/strong[@class="validated-shipping"]')->item(0);
    $company = $xpath->query( '//ul[@class="itemlist" and li[@class="shoppingcol" and p[@class="button" and a[@class="button-a google-analytic-retailer-data"]]]]/*/*/a[@class="google-analytic-retailer-data"]//img/@src')->item(0);

    echo "<div class='div-table-row'>\n";
    echo "<div class='div-table-col'><span>".substr($name->textContent, 0, -18)."</span></div>\n";
    echo "<div class='div-table-col'><img style='display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle' src='".$company->textContent."'><a href='".$line."' target='_blank'><span>".getPRPrice($price->textContent)."</span></a></div>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is some css style so that you can see exactly what I see:

```
.div-table-row{
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.div-table-col{
  float: none;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 250px;         
  display: table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
.div-table-col-title{
  float: none;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 250px;         
  display: table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(30, 139, 45) !important;
}
.productImg{
    display:none; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
span{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left:10px; 
  padding-right:10px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
.span-title{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left:10px; 
  padding-right:10px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

This is how it looks for some of the products of the webpage I try to crawl

[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7spZ3.png)

But the span that I take for the name seems like it is not returned completely.

[product from Pricerunner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwByS.png)

Does anyone have an idea about the issue?

Thank you!

**EDIT!! I used the following links for testing it:**

```
http://www.pricerunner.dk/pl/1-3140663/Mobiltelefoner/Microsoft-Lumia-650-Sammenlign-Priser
http://www.pricerunner.dk/pl/1-3098807/Mobiltelefoner/Apple-iPhone-6S-64GB-Sammenlign-Priser
http://www.pricerunner.dk/pl/1-3141579/Mobiltelefoner/Samsung-Galaxy-S7-Edge-32GB-Sammenlign-Priser 
http://www.pricerunner.dk/pl/1-3154462/Mobiltelefoner/HTC-10-32GB-Sammenlign-Priser
```

Comment: Too long selectors for `$price` and `$company`, that makes debugging even harder. And you've put four slashes in the selector for `$name`. Now, It seems you don't get the data you need, so what do you actually get, and what are you expecting to get?

Comment: the text from that span. In stead of "Microsoft Lumia 650" I am getting only "M". There is no product from which I receive the full name... some of them give me more letters or even words, but some give me nothing. I edited the post and added the links I tested with.

Comment: `$price` and `$company` are just fine. I am receiving exactly what I need from them. My problem is only with `$name`

Comment: `$name = $xpath->query( '//span[@class="fn"]')->item(0)->textContent;` what do you get if you try `echo $name;` (no transformation). I think the problem comes from the `substr` you apply afterwards

Comment: yeah.. you are right.. so dumb mistake. Thank you :|

Comment: @smarber: Right now this question sits at the top of the "XPath" questions list, as one that has not received any answers. Please post an answer so others don't waste time coming here to read it and then find out it's already solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me

```
// Please notice the use of only two slashes and not four like you did
$name = $xpath->query('//span[@class="fn"]')->item(0)->textContent;
```

The problem comes from the `substr` you apply afterwards

Comment: This can be optimized to `$name = $xpath->evaluate('string(//span[@class="fn"])')`.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing! The issue was a the `substring` that was cutting the `$name` variable. I used it for removing something from the name some time ago.